# rxjs scan default properties upon first call

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following rxjs component:

```
search$ =  this.searchCriteria$.pipe(
    switchMap((search: SearchProgramsCriteria) => this.httpService.getProgramsSearchList(search)),
    scan((acc, curr)=>{

      /* Record the min and max pages we've already visited START */
      // If the current page is lower than the currently marked acquired one, then adjust our min number
      if ((curr.pagination.current_page < acc.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired)){
        acc.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired = curr.pagination.current_page;
      }

      // If the current page is higher than the currently marked acquired one, then adjust our max number
      if ((curr.pagination.current_page > acc.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired)){
        acc.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired = curr.pagination.current_page;
      }
      /* Record the min and max pages we've already visited END */

      /* Depending on the desired loading direction, we either put it at the top or the bottom of the existing array START */
      if ((this.loadingDirection === "top")){
        acc.data.unshift(...curr.data);
      }
      else
      {
        acc.data.push(...curr.data);
      }
      /* Depending on the desired loading direction, we either put it at the top or the bottom of the existing array END */
      
      return acc;
   }),
    tap((res) => {
      this.unsetLoadingDirection();
    })
  );
```

And it calls the following httpservice observable:

```
getProgramsSearchList(searchCritieria: any): Observable<SearchPrograms> {
      return this.http
          .post<SearchPrograms>(`myapi/programs`, searchCritieria, { responseType: 'json' })
          .pipe(
            map((clients: any) => ({
              pagination: {
                total: clients.pagination.total,
                current_page: clients.pagination.current_page,
                ['sort-order']: clients.pagination['sort-order'],
                ['sort-by']: clients.pagination['sort-by'],
                minPageNumberAcquired: clients.pagination.current_page,
                maxPageNumberAcquired: clients.pagination.current_page
              },
              data: clients.data.map((client: any) => ({
                  id: client.id,
                  name: client.meta.name
              }))
            })),
            catchError((err) => {
              return this.errorHandler(err);
            })
          );
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Top loading START -->
            <div class="align-center p-button-tertiary top-loading-button" *ngIf="(loadingDirection === null) && (searchData.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired > 1)">
                <a [href]="'/search-programs?page='+(searchData.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired-1)" (click)="loadAtTop($event, searchData.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired-1)" class="p-button">
                    <span class="p-button-label">Load more</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="skeleton-card" *ngIf="loadingDirection === 'top'">
                <div class="skeleton-1zyqvjb96qq"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Top loading END -->

            <div class="programs-search-results">
                <ul>
                    <app-program-card *ngFor="let item of searchData.data; let i = index" [detail]="item" [count]="i"></app-program-card>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Bottom loading START -->
            <div class="skeleton-card" *ngIf="loadingDirection === 'bottom'">
                <div class="skeleton-1zyqvjb96qq"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="align-center p-button-tertiary" *ngIf="(loadingDirection === null) && (searchData.pagination.total >= searchData.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired)">
                <a [href]="'/search-programs?page='+(searchData.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired+1)" (click)="loadAtBottom($event, searchData.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired+1)" class="p-button">
                    <span class="p-button-label">Load more</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Bottom loading END -->
```

My component listens to changes in the query params and upon change it calls the api. My component has quite complex loading in that you can load items at the top and the bottom depending on which load button you press. It will also remember what was the min and max page numbers you've already been on `minPageNumberAcquired` and `maxPageNumberAcquired`. This is in place so you don't go from page 2 => 1 => 2, but instead 2 => 1 => 3.

My component works as is. However in my service I am declaring `minPageNumberAcquired` and `maxPageNumberAcquired` when I really shouldn't be because it will always be the current page number. The problem I have is that `scan` only actions on the second time I call the api but my template needs those `minPageNumberAcquired` and `maxPageNumberAcquired` values from the start in order to work. Is it a case where I need to declare the default value on `scan` somehow?

Something like:

```
scan((acc, curr)=>{
      return acc;
   }, {pagination: acc.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired, acc.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired}),
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, `scan` works like `Array.reduce`, you pass a default value as second argument.

You solution seems fine.

```
scan((acc, curr)=>{
      return acc;
   }, {pagination: acc.pagination.minPageNumberAcquired, acc.pagination.maxPageNumberAcquired}),
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but when attempting to use "acc" at that point it says Cannot find name 'acc'

Comment: [It should work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ieexyg?file=index.ts)

Comment: But if I attempt to change your { foo: '', bar: '' } to { foo: acc, bar: '' } for example it errors. Isn't it out of scope to be used?

Comment: Yes, my bad, you can't use the variable for the default value but you can set it to something like 0.